# "Image" не содержит определение для "FromStream". Не видит метода

Tags: c#

Выдает ошибку "Image" не содержит определение для "FromStream". На всякий случай мои юзинги:

```
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using TagLib;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Drawing;
```

Подчеркивает FromStream, тем самым показывая, что не видит метода:

```
Image image = Image.FromStream();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: visual studio ругается именно на отсутствие метода, добавление параметра не помогает

Comment: А у самого `Image` какое полное имя, какой неймспейс? Может это другой какой-то `Image`, из другого пространства, не из `System.Drawing`. Наведитесь на него или ещё как-то посмотрите. Или по Ctrl+LMK в него зайдите.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась установкой System.Drawing.Common в менеджере пакетов